# Waiting for table metadata lock

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь через ESF Migration ToolKit перекинуть данные с MySql в MsSql, так он почему-то зависает на попытке получить структуру БД.

Если смотреть монитор ресурсов, то стоит какая-то блокировка:

```
Waiting for table metadata lock
```

и шлется запрос такого вида:

```
SELECT f.constraint_name, f.ordinal_position, f.table_name, f.column_name, f.referenced_table_schema, f.referenced_table_name, f.referenced_column_name, r.match_option, r.update_rule, r.delete_rule 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage f 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.referential_constraints WHERE constraint_schema='DbName') r ON r.constraint_name=f.constraint_name 
WHERE f.referenced_table_schema='DbName' AND f.table_name='TableName' AND f.referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY f.constraint_name, f.table_name, f.ordinal_position
```

Название таблицы и бд замазал.

В чем может быть проблема? В БД из которой я пытаюсь вытянуть таблицы никого кроме меня нету...